# streamWriter.Write(content, Encoding.UTF8) vs streamWriter.Write(content)

Tags: c#

What is the difference:

```
var content = "Some string";
streamWriter.Write(content, Encoding.UTF8);
```

vs

```
var content = "Some string";
streamWriter.Write(content);
```

Comment: The second one ensures UTF8 encoding. Meaning the first one may have problems running in methods or API calls that require UTF8 encoding to work.

Comment: StreamWriter.Write() works just like String.Format().  The second argument can be used to fill a {0} in the first argument.  Surely you are not actually doing this, so it is not sensible code.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Microsoft [documentation of StreamWriter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.write(v=vs.110).aspx), there is no such overload for `Write` that takes a string and an encoding. If you want to explicitly specify an encoding, you need to pass it in to one of the constructor overloads of the StreamWriter when you create it.

However, there *are* cases where you may be presented with an overloaded method, one which accepts an encoding and one which doesn't. In answer to your question, the difference is that the first option lets you be explicit about what encoding to use when you serialize the string, and the second option uses a default encoding.

If you are always encoding and decoding within C# code, then it doesn't really matter which one you pick. You could look at the pros and cons of each encoding, and decide to use a specific one, or you could just let C# choose one for you.

If you need to encode in C#, and decode in another language (or vice versa), then you definitely need to be explicit about which encoding you use.